# CUSTOMER_REGISTER_EVENT subscribe not working

Tags: shopware, shopware6

they not call the subscribe Event "CUSTOMER_REGISTER_EVENT". I dont know what i make wrong. PHP:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
        {
    
            return [
                CustomerEvents::CUSTOMER_REGISTER_EVENT => 'onRegistration',
                CustomerEvents::CUSTOMER_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onCustomerGroupWritten',
                ProductEvents::PRODUCT_LOADED_EVENT => 'onProductsLoaded'
            ];
        }
    public function onRegistration(EntityLoadedEvent $event)
        {
            $this->logger->info('ON REGISTER');
        }
```

My services.xml:

```
<services>
    <service id="RegisterChangeClass\Listener\RegisterListener">
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
        <argument type="service" id="customer.repository" />
        <argument type="service" id="router.request_context" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />    
    </service>    
</services>
```

All other events works without problems.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you ?

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            GuestCustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegisterGuest',
            CustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegister'
        ];
    }

    public function onRegister(CustomerRegisterEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Customer register", ["id" => $event->getCustomerId()]);
    }

    public function onRegisterGuest(GuestCustomerRegisterEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info("Guest customer", ["id" => $event->getCustomerId()]);
    }
```

The issue seems to be that the CustomerRegisterEvent is not dispatched with the event name, so it will then use the class as the event name.

Comment: Nice, this works:

`CustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegister'`

Big thanks

GuestCustomerRegisterEvent not works, tested on /account/login and /account/register

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying with a Guestaccount? This would be an other event called
GuestCustomerRegisterEvent.

Comment: Cant find this event?

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.13.0/src/Core/Checkout/Customer/CustomerEvents.php

Comment: its here https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.13.0/src/Core/Checkout/Customer/Event/GuestCustomerRegisterEvent.php

Comment: Thanks, GuestCustomerRegisterEvent not works, but this:

`CustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegister'`

Answer (score 1):

The `$event` parameter has the wrong type. You need to define it as a `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent` like this

```php
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent;
//...
    public function onRegistration(CustomerRegisterEvent $event)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Another gotcha could be, that Double-Optin is activated for the customer-registration (under `Settings -> Login/Registration`).
The event then only gets called in `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterConfirmRoute::confirm`, so when the customer confirms his account by using the link in the DOI-email.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks, i deactivated the double-option, still did not work :(